# How can I load only a foreign key into Nested fields using Marshmallow / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I'm very new to Flask-Marshmallow / Flask-SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to set up my own REST API with flask and mysql.

Here is the payload I'm trying to post. I want to be able to only send the ID and exclude all other fields:

```
{
    "code": "FG034",
    "product_name": "test test2",
    "description": "Description",
    "init_date": "2021-01-10",
    "init_by": {
        "id": "27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c"
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I send that payload:

```
ERROR in utils: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, "Column 'full_name' cannot be null")
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id, full_name, initials, hashed_password, is_active) VALUES (%(id)s, %(full_name)s, %(initials)s, %(hashed_password)s, %(is_active)s)]
[parameters: {'id': '27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c', 'full_name': None, 'initials': None, 'hashed_password': None, 'is_active': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

Which is weird because I'm not trying to insert **anything** into the user table...

When I put all fields in it adds as expected:

```
{
    "code": "FG034",
    "product_name": "test test2",
    "description": "Description",
    "init_date": "2021-01-10",
    "init_by": {
        "id": "27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c",
        "initials": "EE",
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "full_name": "Example Exampleton",
        "is_active": true
    }
}
```

This is the GET for the result of that added FinishedGood (which is what I want):

```
{
    "code": "FG034",
    "init_date": "2021-01-10",
    "description": "Description",
    "id": 3,
    "is_active": true,
    "init_by": {
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "id": "27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c",
        "is_active": true,
        "full_name": "Example Exampleton",
        "initials": "EE"
    },
    "product_name": "test test2"
}
```

Maybe I'm using this completely wrong but can anyone tell me:

1. Why is it trying to insert into the user table? All I want is the primary key to be loaded into init_by_id
2. Is there a way to post a payload with just the ID like I showed at the beginning?

Here are my classes and schemas:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.CHAR(32), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    initials = db.Column(db.String(3), unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        load_instance = True
        sqla_session = db.session

    id = ma.auto_field()
    email = ma.auto_field(required=False)
    full_name = ma.auto_field(required=False)
    initials = ma.auto_field(required=False)
    is_active = ma.auto_field(required=False)

class FinishedGood(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    init_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    init_by_id = db.Column(db.CHAR(32), db.ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    init_by = db.relationship(User)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

class FinishedGoodSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = FinishedGood
        load_instance = True
        sqla_session = db.session

    init_by = ma.Nested(UserSchema)
```

And finally my post method:

```
def post_finished_good():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    fg = FinishedGoodSchema().load(data)
    db.session.add(fg)
    db.session.commit()
    return FinishedGoodSchema().jsonify(fg), 201
```

Comment: Good question, I have a similar problem in my project, only with a many-to-many relationship. The POST action to create a new `A` object can't be allowed to add or update `B` objects for security reasons. I just want to pass in a list of `B` object ids to be associated with the new `A`. Hopefully someone can provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to Marshmallow so this probably isn't an optimal solution, but I managed to find a workaround using the `@pre_load` decorator:

```
@pre_load
def pre_load_process(self, data, **kwargs):
  id = data.get('id')
  if id is None:
    return data

  user = User.query.filter(User.id == id).first()
  if user is None:
    return data

  merged_data = UserSchema().dump(user)
  merged_data.update(data)

  return merged_data
```

Essentially, adding this method to your `UserSchema` class enables it to deserialize from `id` only as in your example payload. If other fields are included as well as `id`, they will overwrite the values pulled from the database.

If you need to prevent the `User` from being updated via the `FinishedGood` endpoint (the equivalent is true of my project) then `FinishedGoodSchema` will also need a `@pre_load` decorated method to strip everything but `id` from the nested `init_by`.

This doesn't seem like a particularly exotic use-case so I'm surprised how difficult it has been to find relevant examples online - all I found was your three-month old question with no answers... Like I said, I'm also a beginner at using this library and would appreciate some context from a Marshmallow expert. When something this ostensibly simple turns out to be a huge headache to implement, it makes me concerned that my whole approach is misconceived.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Change the init_by field to `init_by = autofield()`. Then load the `init_by` member as: `"init_by": "27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c"`.
Create a separate schema for serialization with `init_by = Nested(UserSchema)` to generate the desired output.

```
class User(db.Model):
    # columns omitted for brevity

class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    # fields omitted for brevity

class FinishedGood(db.Model):
    init_by = db.relationship(User)
    # columns omitted for brevity

class FinishedGoodSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = FinishedGood
        load_instance = True
        sqla_session = db.session

        # default is False
        load_relationships = True

    # or
    init_by = autofield()

    # remove this: nested fields seem to apply only for serialization and for loading a new instance 
    # init_by = ma.Nested(UserSchema)
```

Payload:

```
{
    "code": "FG034",
    "product_name": "test test2",
    "description": "Description",
    "init_date": "2021-01-10",
    "init_by": "27bb9e1acad247618fb2c3e016ae841c"
}
```

I have not tested this but feel free to comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Schema as such:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Set unknown to 'exclude' to automatically exclude unknown fields
        unknown = 'exclude'
    init_by = fields.String()

    @pre_load
    def pre_load_process(self, data, many, **kwargs):
        id = data.get('init_by', {}).get('id')
        if id is None:
            return data  # or raise ValidationError
        return {"init_by": id}
```

This will take json input in a format such as you showed and output a dictionary as such: `{"init_by": id}` if the input json is in the expected format.